# python - regex to remove a if it occures after a b

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I want to remove all the dots in a text that appear after a vowel character. how can I do that?

**Here is the code I wish I had:**

```
string = re.sub('[aeuio]\.', '[aeuio]', string)
```

Meaning like keep whatever vowel you have matched and remove the '.' next to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capture the vowel and replace with a backreference to it:

```
import re
s = "Se.hi.mo."
s = re.sub(r'([aeuio])\.', r'\1', s)
print(s) # => Sehimo
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Qrz7qg) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bv2ZYP/1).

Here, `([aeuio])` forms a [*capturing group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and `\1` in the replacement pattern is a [*numbered backreference*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) referencing the text captured into Group 1.

Mind the usage of raw string literals where a backslash does not form an escape sequence: `r'\1'` = `'\\1'`.

Comment: thanks for your great answer and specially tanks for the tip about raw strings:)